# zip the files and folders inside a parent directory without including the parent directory + Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-linux

Is there a Linux command to zip the files and folders inside a parent directory without including the parent directory.
From all the solutions that I tried, the parent directory also is getting zipped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move into the folder, then zip :

```
cd my-folder
zip -r ../my-archive.zip *
```

Dirty, but effective

Or, in a more fancy way, using `tar`:

```
tar czf my-archive.tar.gz -C /path/to/my-foder/ ./
```